# How to put a class in aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm brand new to asp.net.  I added a class to my aspx file and now it does not compile:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Line 206:        }
Line 207:        
Line 208:        private void @__Render__control1(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter @__w, System.Web.UI.Control parameterContainer) {
Line 209:            
Line 210:            #line 7 "c:\aspx\dummy.aspx"
```

I'm not even using the class yet.  The class is simple enough:

```
public class AddressSummary
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string txt { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not using visual studio, just a text editor, so no replies with solutions that involve VS please.

I got the entire file down to this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%
public class AddressSummary
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string txt { get; set; }
}
%>
```

Works without the class.  Can somebody point me in the right direction please.

Comment: `} expected` Error is simple enough. You are missing one `}` at the end.

Comment: No, he is not missing any `}`. Also I don't understand why a perfectly valid question is downvoted and even worse: requested to be closed.

Comment: Any opened bracket `{` needs to be closed with another bracket `}`.

Comment: Yes, and if you count carefully, you will see that the OP has properly closed all the opening brackets.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: If the class is put in its own file e.g. "AddressSummary.cs" that is added to the project / solution that might be better as it will still be usable by the ASPX and be a bit easier to manage rather than put everything in one big file, especially as classes and aspx page gets bigger

Comment: How do I add it to the project/solution when I'm not using VS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To declare a class, you need to put it in a `<script>` tags:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    public class AddressSummary
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string txt { get; set; }
    }
</script>

<%
    // Create an instance of the class declared above
    var a = new AddressSummary();
%>
```

Comment: `<script runat="server">` just enough. No requirement to include language name in type attribute when using server-side script tag.